# React Native: Failed to generate APK output with error: "Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'."

Tags: android, apk, build.gradle, react-native

I am using React Native CLI version 2.0.1, React Native version 0.42 and Gradle version 2.14.1. I am using Windows 10 Home as OS.

I tried to generate APK release output by calling "cd android && gradlew assembleRelease" command but failed to so.

Kindly refer attached for stacktrace and logs. I have tried for several hours to fix this problem but to no avail.

May I know what has gone wrong and how can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer Apologies. English isn't my native language hence it wasn't implied as what you have mentioned. I will take note on that. Hmm...that would be a problem for non-English-native people not to have their posts reviewed prior posting though...

Comment: OK, thanks. Yes, knowing how to best help people who have English as a second language is a hard problem. We want to help as many people as possible, but equally posts need to be clear and detailed, which does require a certain standard of writing and understanding. Stack Overflow now has separate sites in Spanish, Russian and Chinese, so thankfully English is not as much of a requirement as it once was.

Answer (score 0):

Found several workarounds here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5787

However, I am unsure if my issue is related to that. Will update once I have tried out the suggested workarounds.

There is also a React Native PR that might be able to solve this issue:https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/13128/commits